# Does it make sense to remove PHP extension which I do not use?

Tags: php, performance, apache, optimization

> I am not very sure whether it is better suited here or on ServerFault, so please feel free to move it, if needed. I just posted it here because I think it is highly relevant to PHP programmers and more people might be able to help me.

I run PHP application on apache server under Ubuntu. Few days ago I looked into `phpinfo()` and found out that I only use a few of the majority of extensions that are installed and enabled. The list of not used extensions is huge (there is a small chance that some of them I need, but this is easy to determine and enable if so). So among other things there are (explanation of what these things are doing is approximate. It is super easy to find precise description):

- bcmath (arbitrary calculation precision)
- bz2, zip, zlib, phar (archivators)
- dba, PDO (handling databases)
- libXML, simpleXML, XML, XMLReader, XMLWriter, DOM (so many things for handling XML)
- ereg (regular expression. Deprecated long time ago)
- FTP
- gettext (internationalize php application)
- readline (something about command line)
- reflection (ability to reverse engineer classes, interfaces)
- SOAP (write SOAP service/client)
- sysvshm, wddx (no idea)

As you see, the list is huge. I am using Mongo as a storage and all my communication with a server is through ajax (JSON), so I highly doubt I need XML/Dba/SOAP/ftp now or in the near future.

So before going and trying to disable each of them one by one and checking if my app still works, I wanted to ask: does it makes sense to disable them? I know that [disabling unneeded modules from apache can give a reasonable boost in productivity](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-optimize-apache-web-server-performance) of the server, but I have not found any normal tests/calculations of this kind about PHP.

So my question can be better stated in this way: does anyone have done some tests to find out what improvements will I gain from disabling/removing unneeded modules (speed, memory consumption and so on). Please refrain from posting something like 'sure it make sense - remove them', or 'do not remove - you can break something' or even citing 'premature optimization is ...'.

Comment: Perhaps move this to ServerFault ?

Comment: If you think so, I would not be disappointed if you will move it (I do not know how).

Comment: I don't have perms. If you think you'd get a better answer there, just delete the question and repost it there. Probably should wait to see if anyone gives good answers first :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Not really.**
Disabling modules will only reduce the footprint of each Apache+PHP instance.  This can give you a boost indeed, but only at high loads / heavy traffic.  As far as process starting / context switching is not a major bottleneck, you're safe with all your modules enabled.

**Then again...**
A very clear exception is xdebug. It's not really a module but if you leave it on, it's gonna cost you around 200-400ms per request. Big numbers, especially since Google started rewarding fast(er) sites. Debuggers and profiles must be OFF for production.

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely. If you're loading things that you aren't using, you are being wasteful. While you might not notice this in many cases, once you get a site that's somewhat active then you will notice the impact!

But beware: if you're going to optimise by removing unnecessary things, then using a library like jQuery could be hypocritical unless you're using every single feature it provides ;) That's one of my main reasons for not using jQuery and instead writing my own "precision" tools to do exactly what I want and nothing more. And my users have noticed the difference! Do not underestimate the power of removing superfluous elements!

Comment: Sorry, but this is exactly the answer I was not looking for. It is kind of obvious that loading the things I am not using is wasteful. I am looking for the answer how much is it waistful. Quantitative approach, not qualitative.

Comment: I don't think quantity matters. If you're being wasteful, then it would be better not to be wasteful, regardless of how much it is.

Comment: agree, but I already know it and asking for clarification about the things I do not know. So to summarize: the things I know - I need to disable it, the things I do not know how much will it help approximately.

Comment: It's always a question of the amounts CHANGING.  If you have a heavy piece of furniture, you're cool with it as long as you don't want to move it. So, speaking about web server processes, they're pre-spawned and ready to fly because it's much faster than launching new processes (or threads) on demand. This works pretty well. Typically, if you have a low CPU load (somewhere in 0-n where n is the number of processors you have), removing unnecessary modules won't help much, you gain like 3-5%. At high loads, just do whatever you can to minimize web server process sizes AND the number of them.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol this post is beautiful, i wish more people would think like you. Of course jquery et simila can be useful to get some things done quickly, but performance-wise no-no!

Comment: This answer is not useful.

Comment: Since when is jQuery a PHP extension?